# Classifying Input Data in Excel via "IF" Statement

Tags: excel, templates

I am creating a template for a schedule of items that requires an input sheet, in order to help with the cleanliness of the final table. However, I am having trouble with the last calculation.

I need an "if" statement to determine whether the item is either "Cash," "Cash Equivalent," "Short Term," or "Needs Research"(the "if false" value for the entire statement).

```
Code: =IF(I4='Product Codes'!B7OR(I4='Product Codes'!B8,I4='Product 
Codes'!B9,I4='Product Codes'!B10,I4='Product Codes'!B11,I4='Product 
Codes'!B12,I4='Product Codes'!B13),"Cash"and(if(Inputs!I4='Product 
Codes'!B18or(Inputs!I4='Product Codes'!B19,Inputs!I4='Product 
Codes'!B20,Inputs!I4='Product Codes'!B21),"Cash 
Equivilents"and(if(Inputs!I4='Product 
Codes'!B22or(Inputs!I4='ProductCodes'!B23),"Short-Term","Needs Research"))))"Needs Research")
```

(The above is a copy of the code that I have been tampering with. I think I have been closer but this is what I have)

In order for the items to reach one of these three classifications, they need to identify with one of five product codes that are listed in another sheet in the workbook. I would like this to be one statement, so that when the data dump comes, all that needs to happen is a copy/paste, and the schedule will be created. Please assist if possible, as any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: This is not a jobs board. You show some code, explain how it isn't working, we (maybe) try to help fix it.

Comment: I'm new to this deep of coding, as by trade I am an investment analyst. However, I posted the code I have built, above.

Comment: The best way would be to put another column by your descriptions in `Product Codes` column B that has the desired output.  So in Column C in that sheet you would put `Cash`,`Cash Equivalents`, etc.  Then you can use a simple vlookup `=VLOOKUP(I4,'Product Codes'!B:C,2,FALSE)`  This helps when one wants to update the descriptions or output.  One does not need to adjust many formula but only the lookup table.

Comment: @ScottCraner that makes sense, however, my issue is that in order for an item to be (lets say, "cash") the product code dumped into the input sheet must match a product code in the "product codes" sheet. If the match is there, it would post the word "cash" in that column of the input sheet. Within this statement, I want to be able to calculate whether the item being dumped is one of 13 possible product codes, which then become one of three product types. Any product code that isn't one of the 13 options would result in "Needs Research"

Comment: See my answer.  It does exactly that.

Comment: Thank you very much! Extremely helpful!

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner . I seem to have another small issue. Is it possible for me to do that VLookup for more than two columns? I just got a new style of report from our custodian, and it uses a new form of description. Rather than a product code, it provides a product description. I need to now be able to use either the code or the description to result in one of the 4 "type" options.

Comment: Yes, in the iferror second criteria add another iferror(vlookup(...),"Needs Review") to look through the second column that you put in the lookup table.  If that is not enough you will  need to ask another question with its own post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment in the `Product Codes` sheet I set up a small lookup table like this:

[image]

Then on my sheet I used a VLOOKUP with An IFERROR to deal with what was not found:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I4,'Product Codes'!B:C,2,FALSE),"Needs Review")
```

[image]